# Reading pipe-delimited file with html tags using Pandas into data-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I've been reading a pipe-delimited data file in Mac with Pandas/Python. The data file contains chat transcripts without a header. The header info that we can give is `ID | Name | transcripts_text`

The sample text file is:

P37001 | John | Thanks for reaching out. Our customer support agents `can&rsquo;t`(can't) accept all applications or provide status through any of our contact channels, including phone and messaging.`<br />`

`<br />`

You can use our `<a href="https://www.google.com/">` `<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Payment Program</span></a>` to apply for a loan. To check the status of your loan or for additional questions, please go to `the&nbsp`;

``` <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">``<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"> ```Pay Program `</span></a>.<br /> &nbsp;`
``` <p>To apply for loan on your check Program loan, visit <a href="http://google.com/" ``target="_blank"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">google.com/</span></a>.</p> ```

`<br />`

`<br />`

`&nbsp;`

P37002 | John | `<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 205);"><strong>XX FORMAL MALE XX</strong></span><br />`

To collect your personal information, a secure form will be available in the next few minutes within our conversation. When you see the message box change to the secure form, you can safely enter

`&quot;Submit&quot;`. After selecting "Submit" the message box will return and you can enter additional details of a non-personal nature into our conversation.`<br />`

`<br />`

``` <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 205);"><strong>XX FORMAL FEMALE XX</strong></span>``<br /> ```
To collect your personal information, a secure webform will be available in the next few minutes within our conversation. When you see the message box change to the secure webform, you can safely enter your personal data and select `&quot;Submit&quot;`. After selecting `&quot;Submit&quot;` the message box will return and you can enter additional details of a non-personal nature into our conversation.

`<br />`

`<br />`

`<br />`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
quick_reply=pd.read_csv('final.txt', names=['ID','Name','transcripts_text'], sep='|')
```

Output:

```
  ID     Name   transcripts_text
 P37001  John   Thanks for reaching out. Out..
 <br />  NaN      NaN
```

Expected Output:

```
   ID     Name   transcripts_text
 P37001  John   Thanks for reaching out. Our customer support agents can't accept all applications or provide status through any of our contact channels, including phone and messaging.You can use our ..
```

`Removing all the html tags. And the data is captured properly in pandas data frame considering P37001 data as single row and P37002 as second row`

Comment: Are there unquoted newline characters in your file?

Comment: There is this character `&nbsp;` before beginning of new id's and sometimes it's there and sometimes it's not there.  So there is no definite delimiter to identify new line ( by this I mean new `ID`)

Comment: Please try to remove mess from your question. For more information about [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) read this article!

Comment: I'm not talking about escaped HTML entities; you seem to have linebreaks in your data. However, that's how different records are delimited.

Comment: Yes, the line breaks are there in original text file as well. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML document as a text file, you can try to install beautiful soup and parse the HTML document, after.that you can send that string (or maybe you can overwrite the original file) to pandas. You can check [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) how to print with `soup.get_text()`

Comment: It is not a HTML document. It's a text file with some html tags and encoded text

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, as you have processed the data only and you need some cleaning..

```
>>> df
        ID  Name                transcripts_text
0   P37001  John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
1  <br />    NaN                             NaN
```

### Solution 1:

```
>>> df[~df['ID'].str.contains("<br />")]
       ID  Name                transcripts_text
0  P37001  John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
```

OR

```
>>> df[~df.ID.str.contains("<br />", na=False)]
       ID  Name                transcripts_text
0  P37001  John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
```

Or

As if you have multiple strings at the start of the line which you want to like:

```
>>> df[~df['ID'].isin(['spl'])]
        ID      Name                transcripts_text
0   P37001      John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
1  <br />        NaN                             NaN
2    &nbsp  sometext                        sometext
```

Solution:

```
>>> df[~df['ID'].str.contains("<br />|&nbsp")]
       ID  Name                transcripts_text
0  P37001  John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
```

OR

Create a list of strings you want to remove and pass it with `join`.

```
>>> spl =['<br />', '&nbsp']
>>> df[~df['ID'].str.contains('|'.join(spl))]
       ID  Name                transcripts_text
0  P37001  John  Thanks for reaching out. Out..
```

Comment: Can we make new line based on ID column that start with `P3***` ?

Comment: Do you mean select only rows which startswith `P3***` only? if  this is the case then yes we can. else you may explain little more.